# “I am of the opinion that” vs. “I think that”

Tags: grammar

“I am of the opinion that” vs. “I think that”

Do the two phrases have exactly the same meaning? If not, could you please explain it and give me some example sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two phrase have roughly the same meaning.

“I am of the opinion that” is more formal, and implies a more deliberate and considered process of forming the opinion. "I think that" is more casual in usage, and also implies a more casual process of coming to a conclusion. But in most contexts they can be used interchangeably.